# Create Node.js apps using SQL Server on macOS

Tags: sql, node.js, command-prompt

I am installing SQLCMD. My Command:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P your_password
```

But there is an error was showing...

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2726.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specifc error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the port on your server in your sqlcmd.

-S [protocol:]server[instance_name][,port]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15